# Composer finds a package by search but not by require

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I added new package at packagist.org [karu/simple-js-localization](https://packagist.org/packages/karu/simple-js-localization).

When I run composer search with my package name, I can find it

[image]

but when I run composer required the package is not there.

[image]

Shell script that I run.

```sh
composer search karu/simple-js-localization

composer require karu/simple-js-localization
```

Why does this happen? what's the difference between search and require in this regard?

PS: I checked packagist twitter no update on any issue. 
Waited more than 3 hours.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Enable to reproduce, https://i.imgur.com/Yyobn5r.png

Comment: @CaddyDZ Thanks for your info. I updated my question.

Comment: Composer found your package, it just couldn't find a compatible minimum stability version

Comment: Here's a [PR](https://github.com/karunais13/laravel-js-localization/pull/1) that fix it

Comment: Initial was set dev but still couldn't find it also. I already accepted your PR. Let me check again after some time. Thanks

Comment: @CaddyDZ The issue still persists. I getting the same error. https://imgur.com/lzDNkdW

Comment: I think the issue due to composer latest update [issue-link](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8347)

Comment: What's your composer version?

Comment: Composer version 1.9.0

Comment: Create a new empty folder somewhere else and require the package, you'll see that it works, there's no issue with composer

Comment: Maybe a cache issue ? Did you try `composer clearcache && composer require karu/simple-js-localization` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Issue was with the Singapore mirror for the packagist metadata. Composer developer team fixed it. [Check here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8347)